# How to have a global click Listener for multiple buttons in the same layout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-appcompat

Suppose if we are having 50 Buttons in a layout instead of creating click listeners for each buttons.

Eg:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

If we have 50 Buttons like this there will be lot of bloatware code.

Is there any other way to implement this efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried implementing [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)?

Comment: Or implement Databinding

Comment: Both of these I haven't tried

Comment: iterate through childviews of your layout, and set them click listener, if they are buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop the view children after setting up your layout, so, lets say that these buttons are all children of your main view then loop all view children, then check for Button instances and assign your listener.

Comment: This method works...I have implemented it using the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want all the buttons to have a same clickListener? If yes, then you can created your own button that extends the Android Button class, and initialize clickListener there.

```
class MyButton(context: Context,...) : android.widget.Button(context,...) {

    init {
        this.setOnClickListener {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your layouts, use `MyButton` instead of `android.widget.Button`